# Add one to an xsl variable if there are one or more matching elements

Tags: variables, xslt

I'm working on an xsl transform that is creating item numbers.  It includes statements like this:

```
data-item-no="{$itemOffset + count(list//para)}"
```

This is fine when I want to add the number of para elements to $itemOffset, but in this case the paras are all rolled up into a single item.  I want to add 0 if there are no matches for "list//para" and 1 if there is one or more "list//para". How can I do this in xsl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can make it explicit with

```
$itemOffset + (if (list//para) then 1 else 0)
```

In XSLT 1.0 make use of the fact that

- an empty node set coerces to boolean false
- a non-empty node set coerces to boolean true
- boolean false coerces to the number 0
- boolean true coerces to the number 1

So:

```
$itemOffset + boolean(list//para)
```

(the `+` operator implicitly coerces its arguments to be numbers)